# How to use the PickerStyle protocol in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I'm trying to make my own custom picker style using the `PickerStyle` protocol, but is it even possible to use it? if so, how do I use it?

When I conform to the protocol it creates the follow functions:

```swift
static func _makeView<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_PickerValue<DropdownPickerStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewInputs) -> _ViewOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
        
}
    
static func _makeViewList<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_PickerValue<DropdownPickerStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewListInputs) -> _ViewListOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
        
}
```

Comment: The underscore prefixes are a good sign that you are not supposed to make your own implementations of `PickerStyle`.

Comment: I guess I'll have to make my own picker.